# Sending 'AT' command to usb GSM modem return empty string in Python

Tags: python, linux, usb, pyserial

#### The Problem

I'm setting up a script in python to communicate with my USB GSM Modem through AT commands.
So to test the communication is working correctly I first try to send a simple `AT` expecting to receive an `OK`, but instead with every `read` request I still receive only empty strings.
I'm following the AT standard as explained here: [AT Commands](https://www.engineersgarage.com/tutorials/at-commands)

#### So far

Working on Linux Mint 18.
I found more information about my GSM with [mmcli](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/man/1.0.0/mmcli.8.html).
Launching `mmcli -L` result in:

```
$ mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [D-Link,Inc  ] D-Link DWM-157
```

and then the informations:

```
$ mmcli -m /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 
  --------------------------
  General  |      dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |      device id: 741cce5b5eb40d9ac1c9a1dc0dfa2356f0abe3e7
  --------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: D-Link,Inc  
           |          model: D-Link DWM-157
           |       revision: MOLY.WR8.W1231.DC.WG.MP.V3
           |   h/w revision: MTK2
           |      supported: gsm-umts
           |        current: gsm-umts
           |   equipment id: 355620059754511
  --------------------------
  System   |         device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5
           |        drivers: cdc_mbim, option1
           |         plugin: Generic
           |   primary port: cdc-wdm2
           |          ports: ttyUSB0 (at), wwp0s29f7u5 (net), ttyUSB1 (at), 
           |                 cdc-wdm2 (mbim)
  --------------------------
  Numbers  |            own: 393515383117
  --------------------------
  Status   | unlock retries: unknown (0)
           |          state: registered
           |    power state: on
           |    access tech: hsdpa, hsupa
           | signal quality: 0% (cached)
  --------------------------
  Modes    |      supported: allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: none
           |        current: allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: none
  --------------------------
  IP       |      supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------
  3GPP     |           imei: 355620059754511
           |  enabled locks: net-pers, net-sub-pers, provider-pers, corp-pers
           |    operator id: 22250
           |  operator name: 22250
           |   registration: home
  --------------------------
  SIM      |      dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
```

So to check my GSM is able to respond to `AT` i used [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat):

```
$ sudo socat - /dev/ttyUSB0
AT

OK
```

#### Final Goal

I'm aiming to create a script that allows me to send multiple SMS to a list of numbers.

#### Complete Script

```py
import serial, time

def initSerial() :
    print ('initialize...', end='')
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
    ser.baudrate = 115200
    ser.timeout = 5                     #timeout block read
    ser.writeTimeout = 2
    ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS     #number of bits per bytes
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE     #set parity check: no parity
    ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE  #number of stop bits
    ser.xonxoff = False                 #disable software flow control
    ser.rtscts = False                  #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
    ser.dsrdtr = False                  #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
    ser.open()
    print('done')
    return ser


def write_cmd(ser,cmd) :
    if ser.isOpen() :   
        print('writing: " {} " in {}'.format(cmd, ser.name))
        ser.write(cmd.encode('utf-8'))  # Write the 'cmd' encoded with utf-8


def read_until(ser,terminator='\n'):
    print ('reading {}...'.format(ser.name))
    resp = ''
    while not ( resp.endswith(terminator) or resp.endswith('\r') ) : # If the string is not terminated
        tmp = ser.read(1)   # Read and store in a temp variable
        if not tmp : return resp # timeout occured
        resp += tmp
    return resp  


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    ser = initSerial()          # Setup initial variables and configurations
    write_cmd(ser,'AT\r\n')         # Write a command to the serial pipe
    print(read_until(ser))      # Read from the serial pipe until 
    ser.close()
```

This is the output:

```
$ sudo python3 main.py 
  initialize...done
  writing: " AT " in /dev/ttyUSB0
  reading /dev/ttyUSB0...
```

There is a blank line there.

Answer (score 0):

The AT Commands work according to a specific sintaxis. In this case, I would say that the problem is that you are sending the `AT` without the ending lines. It is necessary that you send all the **AT Commands** at the end with the carrier and end line character. So in this case would be `AT\r\n`, and all your commands to communicate with the device should be finished in the same way.

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :
ser = initSerial()          # Setup initial variables and configurations
write_cmd(ser,'AT\r\n')     # Write a command to the serial pipe
print(read_until(ser))      # Read from the serial pipe until 
ser.close()
```

The response of every AT Command changes depends which command you are using. I suggest that you use another code more elaborate to receive the RX Signal.

Comment: I tried as you suggested writing `'AT\r\n'` and also with  `'AT\r'` and  `'AT\n'`.
Unfortunately doesn't change the results.
Thank you for the advice about the receiving code, I'll improve it after I've resolved the communication problem.

Comment: What are you using to send the information between your computer and your module? Have you tested also the baud rate? Maybe you are using a higher baud rate for the device

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something is preventing your code returning with an error.

For Python 3.x `serial.read()` returns bytes so where you do:

```
resp += tmp
```

You should get an error (I got it when I run your code connecting two serial ports together in my laptop).

Change that line to:

```
resp += tmp.decode()
```

See here for more details: [Why does pyserial for python3k return bytes while python2k returns strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523342/why-does-pyserial-for-python3k-return-bytes-while-python2k-returns-strings)

The only reason I can think of for you not to get this type conversion error is because you're not receiving anything at all on your port (your code jumps that line on an empty reading from the port). If that's the case I guess you would have to check your settings because your Python code works just fine.